# Setting "Flags" for a run in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

When looking at the list of recent builds for a Plan in Bamboo, there is column in the summary called "Flags". It contains values like "Custom build" (if you started the build manually using "Run customized") and "Custom revision" (if you ran the build against something other than the head of master).

Is it possible to add a step to my Plan that potentially puts my own value in this field for the current build? In particular, I want to have logic that does this based on build variable, basically saying "if this variable equals this value, then add this custom tag to this build" and have the tag show up in that column of the summary, letting me see whether each build used that specific value for the build variable.

Comment: Might be better to ask this in [Atlassian Community](https://community.atlassian.com/) or even log a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for will require two plugins created by Atlassian:

1. [Conditional Tasks for Bamboo](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219706/conditional-tasks-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview).  This will allow you to trigger tasks based on variables.
2. [Inject Variables](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/archive/1210847).  This will allow you to set certain variables in your tasks which can even be picked up by the other plugin.